# Don't understand error message on SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've got three tables: users, funds, and fund types. Each fund has a fund type, each user has a list of funds, and each user can also have a list of fund types that they have created.

Schema:

```
class Fund(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fds_funds'
    fds_fund_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fds_name = Column(String(128))
    fds_symbol = Column(String(5))
    fds_fdt_fund_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fdt_fund_type_id'))
    fund_type = relationship('FundType', backref=backref('fds_funds', uselist=False))


class FundType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fdt_fund_types'
    fdt_fund_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fdt_type_name = Column(String(128))
    fdt_usr_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('usr_user_id'), nullable=True)


user_funds = Table('usf_user_funds', Base.metadata,
    Column('usf_usr_user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('usr_users.usr_user_id')),
    Column('usf_fds_fund_id', Integer, ForeignKey('fds_funds.fds_fund_id'))
)

class User(Base):
    """
    Application's user model.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'usr_users'
    usr_user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    usr_email = Column(Unicode(50))
    _usr_password = Column('password', Unicode(64))

    fund_types = relationship('FundType', foreign_keys='FundType.fdt_usr_user_id')
    funds = relationship('Fund', secondary=user_funds)
```

I'm following the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html), and it appears to very clearly say that the first argument to the foreign key designation should be the column name, not the table name, but I'm getting this error when I run the initialize_DB script:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'fdt_fund_types.fdt_usr_user_id' could not find table
>   'usr_user_id' with which to generate a foreign key to target column
>   'None'

Have I misread the documentation?

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure I do think that you should move the order around? Initialize the table that you are using as foreign key before.

Comment: @1478963 That may be true, but I don't think that would be the cause of the problem here, because the error message is saying that it's trying to find a table named after a column... If it was looking for the correct table and just not finding it I would say that you might be on to something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what fixed it, but I did some rearranging and messing with the references. For posterity, this works:

```
user_funds = Table('usf_user_funds', Base.metadata,
    Column('usf_usr_user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('usr_users.usr_user_id')),
    Column('usf_fds_fund_id', Integer, ForeignKey('fds_funds.fds_fund_id'))
)

class User(Base):
    """
    Application's user model.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'usr_users'
    usr_user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    usr_email = Column(Unicode(50))
    _usr_password = Column('password', Unicode(64))

    fund_types = relationship('FundType', foreign_keys='FundType.fdt_usr_user_id')
    funds = relationship('Fund', secondary=user_funds)   


class FundType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fdt_fund_types'
    fdt_fund_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fdt_type_name = Column(String(128))
    fdt_usr_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('usr_users.usr_user_id'), nullable=True)

class Fund(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fds_funds'
    fds_fund_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fds_name = Column(String(128))
    fds_symbol = Column(String(5))
    fds_fdt_fund_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fdt_fund_types.fdt_fund_type_id'))
    fund_type = relationship('FundType', backref=backref('funds', uselist=False))
```

Comment: Originally you had `ForeignKey('usr_user_id')` in `FundType`, which you've fixed in this version to contain the table name as well.